# I can't visualize the column "characteristics" in my table nor on phpmyadmin

Tags: java, netbeans, phpmyadmin

I'm new to this site
My question is that once I move all information into the table to go each  of its columns, every one of those adds but not my "characteristics" column and it doesn't appear either in the phpmyadmin

**Frame habitacion**

```
import Datos.vhabitacion;
import Logica.fhabitacion;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class FrmHabitacion extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public FrmHabitacion() {
    initComponents();
    mostrar("");
    inhabilitar();
}

private String accion = "guardar";

    // instancias
    vhabitacion dts = new vhabitacion();
    fhabitacion func = new fhabitacion();

    dts.setNum_hab(txtnumero.getText());

    int seleccionado = cbopiso.getSelectedIndex();
    dts.setPiso_hab((String) cbopiso.getItemAt(seleccionado));

    dts.setDescripción_hab(txtdescripcion.getText());
```

**I believe the error is at this line as I get the error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException here.**

```
    dts.setCaracteristicas_hab(txtcaracteristicas.getText());
```

I know it might be silly but I just can't seem to find the mistake

```
    //string to double
    dts.setPrecio_noche(Double.parseDouble(txtprecio_diario.getText()));

    seleccionado = cboestado.getSelectedIndex();
    dts.setEstado_hab((String) cboestado.getItemAt(seleccionado));

    seleccionado = cbotipo_habitacion.getSelectedIndex();
    dts.setTipo_hab((String) cbotipo_habitacion.getItemAt(seleccionado));

    if (accion.equals("guardar")) {
        if (func.insertar(dts)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "La habitación fue registrada satisfactoriamente" );
            //mostrar todos los registros
            mostrar("");
            inhabilitar();
        }

    }else if(accion.equals("editar")){
        dts.setIdhabitacion(Integer.parseInt(txtidhabitacion.getText()));

        if (func.editar(dts)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "La habitación fue editada satisfactoriamente" );
            mostrar("");
            inhabilitar();
        } 
    }

**btnDelete**
  if (!txtidhabitacion.getText().equals("")) {
        int confirmacion = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "Estás seguro de eliminar la habitación?", "Confirmar", 2);

        if (confirmacion == 0) {
            fhabitacion func = new fhabitacion();
            vhabitacion dts = new vhabitacion();

            dts.setIdhabitacion(Integer.parseInt(txtidhabitacion.getText()));
            func.eliminar(dts);
            mostrar("");
            inhabilitar();
        }


    }

private void tablalistadoMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    btnguardar.setText("Editar");
    habilitar();
    btneliminar.setEnabled(true);
    accion = "editar";

    int fila = tablalistado.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());

    txtidhabitacion.setText(tablalistado.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString());
    txtnumero.setText(tablalistado.getValueAt(fila, 1).toString());

    cbopiso.setSelectedItem(tablalistado.getValueAt(fila, 2).toString());
    txtdescripcion.setText(tablalistado.getValueAt(fila, 3).toString());
    //error
    txtcaracteristicas.setText(tablalistado.getValueAt(fila,4).toString());
    //txtcaracteristicas.setText(tablalistado.getValueAt(fila, 4).toString());
    txtprecio_diario.setText(tablalistado.getValueAt(fila, 5).toString());

    cboestado.setSelectedItem(tablalistado.getValueAt(fila, 6).toString());
    cbotipo_habitacion.setSelectedItem(tablalistado.getValueAt(fila, 7).toString());

}



    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    return link;
}

}
```

**vhabitacion**

```
public class vhabitacion {
private int idhabitacion;
private String num_hab;
private String piso_hab;
private String descripción_hab;
private String caracteristica_lab;
private Double precio_noche;
private String estado_hab;
private String tipo_hab;

public vhabitacion(int idhabitacion, String num_hab, String piso_hab, String descripción_hab, String caracteristica_lab, Double precio_noche, String estado_hab, String tipo_hab) {
    this.idhabitacion = idhabitacion;
    this.num_hab = num_hab;
    this.piso_hab = piso_hab;
    this.descripción_hab = descripción_hab;
    this.caracteristica_lab = caracteristica_lab;
    this.precio_noche = precio_noche;
    this.estado_hab = estado_hab;
    this.tipo_hab = tipo_hab;
}

public vhabitacion() {
}

public int getIdhabitacion() {
    return idhabitacion;
}

public void setIdhabitacion(int idhabitacion) {
    this.idhabitacion = idhabitacion;
}

public String getNum_hab() {
    return num_hab;
}

public void setNum_hab(String num_hab) {
    this.num_hab = num_hab;
}

public String getPiso_hab() {
    return piso_hab;
}

public void setPiso_hab(String piso_hab) {
    this.piso_hab = piso_hab;
}

public String getDescripción_hab() {
    return descripción_hab;
}

public void setDescripción_hab(String descripción_hab) {
    this.descripción_hab = descripción_hab;
}

public String getCaracteristicas_hab() {
    return caracteristica_lab;
}

public void setCaracteristicas_hab(String caracteristicas_hab) {
    this.caracteristica_lab = caracteristica_lab;
}

public Double getPrecio_noche() {
    return precio_noche;
}

public void setPrecio_noche(Double precio_noche) {
    this.precio_noche = precio_noche;
}

public String getEstado_hab() {
    return estado_hab;
}

public void setEstado_hab(String estado_hab) {
    this.estado_hab = estado_hab;
}

public String getTipo_hab() {
    return tipo_hab;
}

public void setTipo_hab(String tipo_hab) {
    this.tipo_hab = tipo_hab;
}
```

**fhabitacion**

```
 public class fhabitacion {

private conexion mysql = new conexion();
private Connection cn = mysql.conectar();
//almacenar cadena de conexión
private String sSQL ="";
public Integer totalregistros;

//mostrar registros base de datos: habitación
public DefaultTableModel mostrar(String buscar){
    DefaultTableModel modelo;

    //vector para guardar título
    String [] titulos = {"ID", "Número", "Piso", "Descripción", "Caracteristica", "Precio", "Estado", "Tipo de habitación"};

    //array para almacenar registros de cada uno de los títulos
    String [] registro = new String[8];


    totalregistros = 0;
    modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);

    sSQL="select * from habitacion where piso_hab like '%"+ buscar + "%' order by idhabitacion";
    //System.out.println(sSQL);

    try {
        Statement st = cn.createStatement();
        //ejecutar statement
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sSQL);

        //navegación de todos los registros
        while(rs.next()){
            registro [0] = rs.getString("idhabitacion");
            registro [1] = rs.getString("num_hab");
            registro [2] = rs.getString("piso_hab");
            registro [3] = rs.getString("descripción_hab");
            registro [4] = rs.getString("caracteristica_lab");
            registro [5] = rs.getString("precio_noche");
            registro [6] = rs.getString("estado_hab");
            registro [7] = rs.getString("tipo_hab");

            totalregistros = totalregistros + 1;
            modelo.addRow(registro);
        }
        return modelo;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
        return null;
    }

}

public boolean insertar(vhabitacion dts){
    sSQL = "insert into habitacion(num_hab,piso_hab,descripción_hab,caracteristica_lab,precio_noche,estado_hab,tipo_hab) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sSQL);
        pst.setString(1, dts.getNum_hab());
        pst.setString(2, dts.getPiso_hab());
        pst.setString(3, dts.getDescripción_hab());
        pst.setString(4, dts.getCaracteristicas_hab());
        pst.setDouble(5, dts.getPrecio_noche());
        pst.setString(6, dts.getEstado_hab());
        pst.setString(7, dts.getTipo_hab());

        int n = pst.executeUpdate();

        if(n != 0){
            return true;

        }else{
            return false;
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
        return false;
    } 
}

public boolean editar(vhabitacion dts){
    sSQL = "update habitacion set num_hab=?,piso_hab=?,descripción_hab=?,caracteristica_lab=?,precio_noche=?,estado_hab=?,tipo_hab=? where idhabitacion=?";

    try {
        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sSQL);
        pst.setString(1, dts.getNum_hab());
        pst.setString(2, dts.getPiso_hab());
        pst.setString(3, dts.getDescripción_hab());
        pst.setString(4, dts.getCaracteristicas_hab());
        pst.setDouble(5, dts.getPrecio_noche());
        pst.setString(6, dts.getEstado_hab());
        pst.setString(7, dts.getTipo_hab());
        pst.setInt(8, dts.getIdhabitacion());

        int n = pst.executeUpdate();

        if(n != 0){
            return true;

        }else{
            return false;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
        return false;
    }

}

public boolean eliminar(vhabitacion dts){
    sSQL="delete from habitacion where idhabitacion=?";
    try {
        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sSQL);

        pst.setInt(1, dts.getIdhabitacion());

        int n = pst.executeUpdate();

        if(n != 0){
            return true;

        }else{
            return false;
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
        return false;
    }


}


}
```

Every column is full except the characteristics one although I completed that part too

[Characteristics can't be visualized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fzS4.png)

[nor here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXw2Y.png)
Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:
I made breakpoint into the line
    pst.setString(4, dts.getCaracteristicas_hab());

and print it but there's no error message and breakpointing doesn't seem that does anything at all either...

[there's no feedback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc7S5.png)

Again, thanks for the help and sorry if the error looks obvious, I am still new into the world of coding!

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? There’s a fair amount of code I imagine can be cut from your post.

Comment: There is a lot of info in here, ]. What do you want? Where is failing ?

Comment: @Gatusko I can't save the characteristics field in my table nor on phpmyadmin. I can't seem to find the mistake,

Answer (score 0):

Ok. `dts.setCaracteristicas_hab(txtcaracteristicas.getText());` Are you getting correctly the data from here? You need to breakpoint to see if you are getting the correct data from here. If not in your insert will be an empty value

```
sSQL = "insert into habitacion(num_hab,piso_hab,descripción_hab,caracteristica_lab,precio_noche,estado_hab,tipo_hab) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sSQL);
        pst.setString(1, dts.getNum_hab());
        pst.setString(2, dts.getPiso_hab());
        pst.setString(3, dts.getDescripción_hab());
        pst.setString(4, dts.getCaracteristicas_hab()); // Breakpoint here and see that was settet correctly the Caractersticas if not is null.
```

Checking your code

```
txtcaracteristicas.setText(tablalistado.getValueAt(fila,4).toString());
```

Here you are getting a null value. So is affecting the save in the Object and the save of the DataBase. So check `tablalistado.getValueAt(fila,4)` and see why you are getting null in here.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, could you check up my edit again please?

Comment: tablalistado.getValueAt(fila,4).toString() Can you print this? And if is it your desired output

Comment: you mean like this?  System.out.print(tablalistado.getValueAt(fila, 4).toString());?

Comment: I suggest Breakpointing but so far try with that and see if is the desired output.